# NOT LIKE on mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a big problem understanding why a query works when using `LIKE` in query and not working when using `NOT LIKE`.

I will post query below:

```
select DISTINCT (mails), name 
from disposable 
    JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT (mail) as mails,
                   CONCAT(toys.firstname, ' ' , toys.lastname) as name 
            FROM toys2 
                join toys ON toys.userid = toys2.id 
            where ( (toyid = '27' or toyid = '29') 
                    and status != 'Sold' 
                    and toys.regdate >= '2017-01-01'
                  )
        ) as tab 
WHERE tab.mails LIKE CONCAT('%@', disposable.email)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working" ...? Its not returning anything at all, or not returning what you expect?

Comment: is returning results as if the comparison doesn't take place

Comment: There' no `NOT LIKE` in that query above

Comment: `is returning results as if the comparison doesn't take place ` Was it not supposed to?

Comment: I think you need to escape `%` symbol, try to change at last line : `tab.mails LIKE CONCAT('\%@', disposable.email)`

Comment: Can you provide some sample rows of your database and write which rows shall be returned or not?

Comment: the query above works , if i'm using same query but instead of LIKE is NOT LIKE, it doesn't take effect

it's supposed to return results without those matching from disposable.email

Comment: the idea is the following ==> i'm gettings a list of emails in this format **test@test.com** and got domains in another table in this format **test.com**. What i want to accomplish is to get the list of emails without those matching domains from 2nd table, therefore, using Concat for that. If i use like iget emails matching the domains from second table, if i want to get results without those matches it doesn't work

Comment: Your join between the subquery and the `disposable` table is a bit weird - it doesn't have any conditions at all; instead you're putting the condition in the `WHERE` clause. But I wonder whether `NOT LIKE` is even a valid condition for a `JOIN`. I suspect an outer join would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is something more like the following. Note that I simplified the schema a bit so as to do a bit less work for the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c241/7).

```
SELECT c.email, c.name
  FROM customer c LEFT JOIN disposable d
    ON SUBSTR(c.email, INSTR(c.email, '@')+1, LENGTH(c.email)-INSTR(c.email, '@')) = d.email
 WHERE d.email IS NULL;
```

Basically, here you're getting the domain of the customer and matching it to the entry in the `disposable` table. The final `WHERE` clause uses `IS NULL` to determine the customer email addresses that are not disposable - use `IS NOT NULL` to find the ones that are.

Hope this helps.

Comment: great help !!! one more help request if a  i may.

some domains i get from substring is like "1.a.'d.email'" . how do i exclude those too? a wildcard before d.email doesn't seem to work

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: the query you gave me does the following: 

cuts string till "@" character and @ including.  i get for e.g. from john@gmail.com => gmail.com which is great. 

on disposable table i got for e.g. bad domain named => 10go.com

now some domains are john@1.10go.com which the query doesn't catch because it compares the strings as is. How do i bypass that ? 

i tried instead of ".... = d.email" --> "...= CONCAT('%', d.email ) , but it doesn't work as expected

Comment: Ah I understand now, you're talking subdomains. I'm not a MySQL expert so I don't know the best way to do that. It might be possible to use LIKE in the join condition instead of =.

Comment: your suggestion one more time took as expected, big thx to you !!